# app.post() method is not working in nodejs. I am unable to identify the error

Tags: html, node.js

This is the html file. I dont think there are any errors in this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1><strong>Calculator</strong></h1>
 <form action="/" method="post">   
 <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
 <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="submit">Calculate</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the nodejs code snippet.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.num1);
    res.send("Thanks for posting");
});

app.listen('3000', () => console.log('working properly'));
```

`app.get()` is working just fine but error in `app.post()`
What needs to be done? I am unable to identify the error.

Comment: const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +"/index.html");
});
app.post("/",(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.num1);
    res.send("Thanks for posting that");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working Properly!");
});

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please be specific on the problem. Are you unable to find the page, you are getting undefined, or what? Besides that, how are you sending the form in your HTML?

Comment: she said `app.get` is working but `app.post` doesn't so definitely its req.body parsing issue

Comment: for context, when a button is clicked on the webpage ,it's supposed to display "Thanks for posting" but that's not happening. I'm using <form action="/" method="post"></form>

Comment: Please share the full HTML code for your form by editing the question, not as a comment. I expect the form to contain an `<input name="num1"/>`.

Comment: It looks like you have problem with npm dependencies. I just test your code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

add - return before res.send("Thanks for posting"); in app.post().